# Black screen instead of "Choose an operating system menu", then normal boot (probably after the 30 seconds)

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I had Windows 10 installed on one partition, and then installed Windows 10 on another partition. The first time I restarted the laptop after the installation finished, I got the "Choose an operating system" (you know, the blue menu with white font) menu (with the two installations) and the 30 seconds time before the auto choose. But then, after the new Windows 10 started, and after the drivers were automatically installed and everything else set up, I restarted the laptop again, and this time there was no "Choose an operating system"" menu - instead there was black screen (with display backlight turned on of course) for some time (probably the 30 seconds) and then the laptop booted into the newly installed Windows 10 (it is set as default now). I tried restarting the laptop several times to confirm that this is the issue. I tried pressing the F12 button at boot, which brings another Windows menu (also blue) from which you can choose the option for the "Choose an operating system" menu. I chose that option, and the "Choose an operating system" menu came up and I could choose between the two installations (the older installation is set as second - non-default choice).

So, I'm very happy that something worse didn't happen, but how can I fix the black screen during the automatic (at laptop turn on) "Choose an operating system" menu. Without breaking something else meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

1. Open Windows 10 Settings
2. Go to System, then About
3. Near bottom, select Advanced system settings
4. New window opens, select the Advanced tab.
5. Click button "Settings" under Start-up and Recovery
6. Enable/check "Time to display list of operating systems", select time
7. Click OK to save the changes.

There is another possibility, the Windows 10 Advances boot option is disabled, this can be forced on via admin command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true
```

I hope one of these solves your question.